# How can I reduce the number of call to constructors in my two classes?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I'm writing a `Cache` class that acts as an extension of `std::unordered_map` that counts references and automatically deletes entries that have no references. It also has a boolean parameter to let the developer choose if he wants to keep the entry in the map even if there are no references.
This class returns values in the form of a `CacheRef` instance. Here are the definitions on the said classes:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class Cache;

template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class CacheRef
{
private:
    using CacheMap = std::unordered_map<TKey, std::tuple<TValue, int, bool>>;
public:
    TValue* value = nullptr;
    
    CacheRef<TKey, TValue>& operator=(const CacheRef<TKey, TValue>&) = delete;
    CacheRef<TKey, TValue>& operator=(CacheRef<TKey, TValue>&& other) = delete;
    CacheRef(const CacheRef<TKey, TValue>& ref) :
    m_validRef(ref.m_validRef), m_valueLocation(ref.m_valueLocation), m_cache(ref.m_cache)
    {
        std::cout << "Reference constructor called" << std::endl;
        initialize();
    }

    CacheRef(CacheRef<TKey, TValue>&& ref) :
    m_validRef(ref.m_validRef), m_valueLocation(ref.m_valueLocation), m_cache(ref.m_cache)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor called" << std::endl;
        initialize();
    }

    CacheRef(typename CacheMap::iterator valueLocation, Cache<TKey, TValue>* cache, bool validRef = true)
        : m_valueLocation(valueLocation), m_cache(cache), m_validRef(validRef)
    {
        std::cout << "Normal constructor called" << std::endl;
        initialize();
    }

    ~CacheRef()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
        if (m_validRef)
        {
            m_cache->deleteReference(m_valueLocation);
        }
    }

private:
    void initialize()
    {
        if (m_validRef)
        {
            value = &std::get<0>(m_valueLocation->second);
            ++std::get<1>(m_valueLocation->second);
        }
    }
    typename CacheMap::iterator m_valueLocation;
    const bool m_validRef;
    Cache<TKey, TValue>* const m_cache;
};

template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class Cache
{
    using ValueInfo = std::tuple<TValue, int, bool>;
    using CacheMap = std::unordered_map<TKey, ValueInfo>;
public:
    Cache() = default;
    ~Cache() = default;
    CacheRef<TKey, TValue> add(const TKey& key, const TValue& value, bool autoCacheDelete = true)
    {
        // Make sure TValue is not in the cache already
        auto pair = find(key);
        if (pair.second)
        {
            return pair.first;
        }
        else
        {
            // Insert in cache map
            ValueInfo val(value, 0, autoCacheDelete);
            std::pair<typename CacheMap::iterator, bool> insert = m_cache.insert(std::make_pair(key, val));
                
            // Return the newly inserted element as a CacheRef
            return CacheRef<TKey, TValue>(insert.first, this, true);
        }
    }
    
    std::pair<CacheRef<TKey, TValue>, bool> find(const TKey& key)
    {
        typename CacheMap::iterator kvp = m_cache.find(key);
        if (kvp == m_cache.end())
        {
            return std::pair<CacheRef<TKey, TValue>, bool>(CacheRef<TKey, TValue>(kvp, this, false), false);
        }
        else
        {
            return std::pair<CacheRef<TKey, TValue>, bool>(CacheRef<TKey, TValue>(kvp, this, true), true);
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (auto element : m_cache)
        {
            std::cout << "Key: " << element.first << "\tValue:" << std::get<0>(element.second) << " #Ref: " << std::get<1>(element.second) << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
        
    void deleteReference(typename CacheMap::iterator where)
    {
        int& numRef = std::get<1>(where->second);
        --numRef;
        if (numRef == 0 && std::get<2>(where->second))
        {
            m_cache.erase(where);
        }
    }

private:
    CacheMap m_cache;
};
```

Here is the test function that runs

```
int main()
{
    Cache<std::string, int> testCache;
    auto ref = testCache.add("myKey", 10);
    testCache.print();
}
```

And here is the output

```
> Normal constructor called //<-- This is an invalid reference being created by Cache::find() called by Cache::add() to check if data already exists
> Move constructor called //<-- Probably called by std::pair constructor from Cache::find()
> Destructor called //<-- First data being destroyed
> Normal constructor called //<-- Real data is created by Cache::add()
> Destructor called //<-- Destroyed the return value of Cache::find() when leaving Cache::add() scope
> Key: myKey    Value:10 #Ref: 1
```

So I guess there are some obvious optimizations that can be done. The first I'm thinking of is to remove the call to `find()` in `add()` but that would then require me to be more cautious about how I use the class so I'd prefer to avoid that.

Also creating an invalid reference costs two constructor calls just to throw away the instance which I don't think is very clean. Actually the whole idea of invalid reference kinda bothers me but I couldn't think of any other return value when `find()` can't find a match

Comment: What compiler options did you use to build your application?  Do you have optimizations turned on in your compile build commands?

Comment: One way would be for `add` to not call your `find`, but to call `m_cache.find(key);` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, which I'm digging up. I would use `std::optional` as a return type from `find`. Thus you don't generate temporary objects:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <optional>

template <typename TValue>
struct ValueInfo {
    TValue value;
    int refCount;
    bool autoCacheDelete;
};

template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class Cache;

template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class CacheRef
{
private:
    using CacheMap = std::unordered_map<TKey, ValueInfo<TValue>>;
    using CacheMapIterator = CacheMap::iterator;
    TValue* value = nullptr;
public:
    CacheRef& operator=(CacheRef const&) = delete;
    CacheRef& operator=(CacheRef&&) = delete;

    CacheRef(CacheRef const& ref)
    : _validRef(ref._validRef), _valueLocation(ref._valueLocation), _cache(ref._cache)
    {
        std::cout << "Reference constructor called\n";
        initialize();
    }

    CacheRef(CacheRef&& ref)
    : _validRef(ref._validRef), _valueLocation(ref._valueLocation), _cache(ref._cache)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor called\n";
        initialize();
    }

    CacheRef(CacheMapIterator valueLocation, Cache<TKey, TValue>* cache, bool validRef = true)
    : _valueLocation(valueLocation), _cache(cache), _validRef(validRef)
    {
        std::cout << "Normal constructor called\n";
        initialize();
    }

    ~CacheRef()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor called\n";
        if (_validRef)
        {
            _cache->deleteReference(_valueLocation);
        }
    }

private:
    void initialize()
    {
        if (_validRef)
        {
            value = &_valueLocation->second.value;
            ++_valueLocation->second.refCount;
        }
    }
    CacheMapIterator _valueLocation;
    const bool _validRef;
    Cache<TKey, TValue>* const _cache;
};

template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class Cache
{
private:
    using CacheMap = std::unordered_map<TKey, ValueInfo<TValue>>;
    using CacheMapIterator = CacheMap::iterator;
public:
    Cache() = default;

    CacheRef<TKey, TValue> add(const TKey& key, const TValue& value, bool autoCacheDelete = true)
    {
        // Make sure TValue is not in the cache already
        auto cacheRef = find(key);
        if (cacheRef.has_value()) return cacheRef.value();
        else {
            // Insert in cache map
            ValueInfo val(value, 0, autoCacheDelete);
            auto [iterator, succeeded] = _cache.insert(std::make_pair(key, val));
            // should prolly check 'succeeded'
            // Return the newly inserted element as a CacheRef
            return CacheRef<TKey, TValue>(iterator, this, true);
        }
    }
    
    std::optional<CacheRef<TKey, TValue>> find(const TKey& key)
    {
        auto cacheIt = _cache.find(key);
        if (cacheIt == _cache.end()) return std::nullopt;
        return CacheRef<TKey, TValue>(cacheIt, this, true);
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (auto const& [key, cacheRef] : _cache)
        {
            std::cout << "Key: " << key << "\tValue:" << cacheRef.value << " #Ref: " << cacheRef.refCount << '\n';
        }
    }
        
    void deleteReference(CacheMapIterator where)
    {
        int& numRef = where->second.refCount;
        --numRef;
        if (numRef == 0 && where->second.autoCacheDelete)
        {
            _cache.erase(where);
        }
    }

private:
    CacheMap _cache;
};

int main()
{
    Cache<std::string, int> testCache;
    auto ref = testCache.add("myKey", 10);
    testCache.print();
}
```

gives:

```
Normal constructor called
Key: myKey  Value:10 #Ref: 1
Destructor called
```